# Webpack is loading module twice

Tags: angularjs, webpack, commonjs

I am using webpack to build my angular.js application.
Given a simple example:

**app.js**

```
var angular = require('exports?window.angular!angular'),
    angularMoment = require('angular-moment');

angular.module('myApp', [angularMoment]);
```

**angular-moment.js**

```
define(['angular', 'moment'], function(angular, moment) {
  // some library code
});
```

Here two ways of import of angular, with loader and just by name. It causes that angular will be injected to page twice and I see following warning in console:

```
WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.
```

Is there a way to make webpack consider both imports of angular as the same module?

My `webpack.conf.js`

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'app': './src/app/app.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ResolverPlugin(
      new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin("bower.json", ["main"])
    ),
    new AngularPlugin()
  ]
};
```

Comment: Do you want to include angular bundled inside of your app? I've found it's easier to load a discrete file first for these kind of libraries that don't play nice with webpack.

Comment: That seems to reasonable solution. Tried to do it, and it works. Would you like to expand solution into awnswer or I can do it by myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to have angular be a stand-alone script and have it configured as an external dependency:

```
module.exports = {
  external: {
      'angular' : 'angular'
  },
  entry: {
    'app': './src/app/app.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ResolverPlugin(
      new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin("bower.json", ["main"])
    ),
    new AngularPlugin()
  ]
};
```